# Json object in Map, how to get hold of it in java?

Tags: java, json, xpages

In an XPages application I have in a sessionScope variable the configuration for the application in JSON format.

I wonder how I can get hold of this configuration again in Java?

I tried:

```java
Map<String, Object> sesScope = ExtLibUtil.getSessionScope();
if (null != sesScope.get("configJSON")){
    JsonJavaObject jsonObject = new JsonJavaObject();
    jsonObject = (JsonJavaObject) sesScope.get("configJSON");
    System.out.println("got object?");
    System.out.println("json " + jsonObject.toString());
}
```

In the console I never get to the "got object?" print statement. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Most likely `null != sesScope.get("configJSON")` is evaluating to false and hence its not going into if block.

Comment: it goes into the block if i add additional sysouts in the beginning of the condition

Comment: Then there should be some stack trace in the logs?

Comment: Before trying to explicitly cast whatever is held in `configJSON` attribute to `JsonJavaObject`, find out the real object type: `System.out.println(jsonObject.getClass().getName());`. How to further deal with the object to get data depends on its type (class). BTW, following the Java naming convention makes the code easier to understand

Comment: I am sorry I forgot to mention I am using the com.ibm.commons.util.io.json.JsonJavaObject class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JavaScript method `JSON.parse` that you use, returns just a plain simple JavaScript object, not the `JsonJavaObject`. You can't use JavaScript object later in Java without additional unnecessary overhead. Don't use `json2.jss`, use `JsonParser` like **Paul Withers** have told.

Change your code that gets JSON from your Notes field:

```js
#{javascript:
    importPackage(com.ibm.commons.util.io.json);
    var jsonText = doc.getItemValueString(itemname);
    var jsonFactory:JsonFactory = JsonJavaFactory.instanceEx;
    var jsonObject = JsonParser.fromJson(jsonFactory, jsonText);
    sessionScope.put('configJSON', jsonObject);
}
```

Modify your provided java code by removing unnecessary line:

```java
Map<String, Object> sesScope = ExtLibUtil.getSessionScope();
if (null != sesScope.get("configJSON")) {
    JsonJavaObject jsonObject = (JsonJavaObject) sesScope.get("configJSON");
    System.out.println("got object?");
    System.out.println("json " + jsonObject.toString());
}
```

You should now be OK.
Hint: if you use `JsonJavaFactory.instance` instead of `JsonJavaFactory.instanceEx`, you'll get `java.util.HashMap` instead of `JsonJavaObject`

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind help Stanislaw. I see now that I started with the wrong assumption that the jsonobject from one class would be easy convertable to another jsonobject from another class. A good learning lesson :-)

Comment: @Malin you can never cast one object to another if they are instances of two unrelated classes

Answer (score 1):

Has the sessionScope variable been set? Use `sesScope.containsKey("configJSON")` to verify. If it's an empty JSON object it will be "{}" rather than null. If you're loading as JSON from a REST service or a Notes Document it may be a String rather than a JsonJavaObject. For parsing a String of JSON, you can use `com.ibm.commons.util.io.json.JsonParser`. The constructor for JsonJavaObject expects a Map, not sure if this is what's being passed in.

Comment: the outcome of sesScope.containsKey("configJSON") is true. I have set the scope variable via sessionScope.put("configJSON", JSON.parse(doc.getItemValueString(itemname))); I parse the text from the Notes field as json via the josn2 library as described here https://xomino.com/2013/12/18/safe-json-parsing-in-xpages-ssjs/

Comment: I see now the object class for the json object is com.ibm.jscript.std.ObjectObject

Comment: If you want to use it in Java, I'd recommend JsonParser. That will convert it to a proper Java JSON object.

Comment: How can I do this? I would like to use someting as JsonJavaObject jsonObject = (JsonJavaObject) JsonParser.fromJson(JsonJavaFactory.instanceEx, json) but this requires a string as input. I have difficulties to cast the com.ibm.jscript.std.ObjectObject to string

Comment: Just pass in `doc.getItemValueString(itemname)` as the value. You don't need to go through `JSON.parse()`

Answer (score -1):

JsonJavaObject is your POJO java class ?
If Yes then please use ObjectMapper of Fasterxml to map your JSON data to the fields of JsonJavaObject class.Use this method to map your json data to any POJO class

```
public final T validateJson(final Map<String, Object> jsonMap, final T temmplateClass) throws Exception {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try {
            // convert JSON string to Map
            String jsonString = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(jsonMap);
            return objectMapper.readValue(jsonString, (Class<T>) temmplateClass);
        } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
            throw new NestableRuntimeException(String.format(ApiCommonConstants.INVALID_JSON_FIELD,
                    e.getPath().get(e.getPath().size() - 1).getFieldName()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new NestableRuntimeException(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I forget to mention that I am using the com.ibm.commons.util.io.json.JsonJavaObject class

Comment: my object turns out to be of class com.ibm.jscript.std.ObjectObject